# How to simplify passing multiple variables into a method with node/javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a method to which I need to pass several variables eg

```
export class MyClass{
  myMethod(a, b, c) {
    // do crazy stuff here
    return a * b * c;
  }
}
```

I want to simplify the method signature by changing it to

```
export class MyClass{
  myMethod(alphabetObject) {
    // do crazy stuff here
    return alphabetObject.a * alphabetObject.b * alphabetObject.c;
  }
}
```

I can't work out how create alphabetObject in node/javascript though.  If I were doing it in C# I'd do:

```
public AlphabetObject()
{
   public string A {get; set;}
   public string B {get; set;}
   public string C {get; set;}

   public static GetMyLetters()
   {
      return new AlphabetObject
      {
          A = 1,
          B = 2,
          C = 3
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a way to do this in Javascript/Node? Or is there a better way to do it in Javascript/Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It can be used to extract values from an object, which is created using a simple [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```
myMethod(alphabetObject) {
    const {a, b, c} = alphabetObject;
    // do crazy stuff here
    return a * b * c;
}

// call like this
myMethod({a: "a thing", b: "b thing", c: "c thing"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create JSON object directly

`alphabetObject = { a:"value", b:"value",c:"value"}`

Then you can access a's value by alphabetObject.a

Comment: This is not a JSON object but an javascript object

Comment: It is one and the same

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).